# C IDE in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

I have decided to code an IDE for C using Python with Tkinter. I tried to use my best functional style and keep functions small. This programme works perfectly in Linux with Python 2.7, but it should be compatible with both Windows and Python 3.x.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import datetime
import glob
import os
import platform

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkMessageBox as pop_up
    import tkFileDialog
else:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.tkMessageBox as pop_up
    import tkinter.tkFileDialog as tkFileDialog


TITLE = "C ide"

WINDOWS_ENDING = ".exe"
LINUX_ENDING = ".out"

EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_SAVE = "Please write the name of the file you want to save in the given field."
EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_OPEN = "Please write the name of the file you want to open in the given field."
INVALID_CHARACTERS_MESSAGE = "Unicode does not allow accented letters, please replace them in the following way: è -> e', à -> a'."
SAVING_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Your text is now stored in the {filename} file"

NO_ERROR = ('', None)


def replace_old_title(new_title):
    """
    Replace the old content of the widget
    file_title with a new title.
    """
    file_title.delete(0, tk.END)
    file_title.insert(tk.INSERT, new_title)


def replace_old_text(new_text):
    """
    Replace the old content of the widget
    main_text with a new title.
    """
    main_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, new_text, "a")


def open_():
    """
    Opens a file using the built-in file explorer,
    and displays its text in the main text field.
    """
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    replace_old_title(filename)
    with open(filename) as f:
        replace_old_text(f.read())


def title_is_empty():
    """
    Return True if the tite is empty.
    """
    return not file_title.get()


def invalid_characters_in_title():
    """
    Handles invalid characters in the
    title widget. Mainly accented letters.
    """
    try:
        __ = file_title.get()
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return True


def invalid_characters_in_body():
    """
    Handles invalid characters in the
    title widget. Mainly accented letters.
    """
    try:
        f.write(main_text.get(1.0, tk.END))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return True


def save(alert=True):
    """
    Saves the content of the main text widget into a file,
    handles any kind of error that may happen.
    If alert is True: showes a pop up message to inform the user if
    the file is saved successfuly.
    """
    if title_is_empty():
        pop_up.showerror("No title.", EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_SAVE)
        return False

    if invalid_characters_in_title():
        pop_up.showerror("Invalid characters", INVALID_CHARACTERS_MESSAGE)
        return False

    filename = file_title.get()

    with open(filename, "w+") as f:
        try:
            f.write(main_text.get(1.0, tk.END))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            pop_up.showerror("Invalid characters", INVALID_CHARACTERS_MESSAGE)
            return False
        if alert:
            try:
                pop_up.showinfo("File saved succesfully.",
                                SAVING_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.format(filename=filename))
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                pop_up.showerror(
                    "Invalid characters",
                    INVALID_CHARACTERS_MESSAGE)


def exec_bash(shell_command):
    """
    Runs a shell_command.
    Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python
    User contributions are licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required.
    """
    event = Popen(shell_command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                  stderr=STDOUT)
    return event.communicate()


def compile_(filename, flags):
    """
    Uses the gcc compiler to compile the file.
    """
    command = "gcc " + filename + " " + flags
    return exec_bash(command)


def system_is(name):
    """
    Returns True if the os is equal to the given name.
    >>> system_is("Linux")
    True # If you are on linux
    False # If you are on Windows or Mac
    """
    operating_system = platform.system()
    if operating_system == name:
        return True


def decide_ending():
    """
    Decides the correct ending of the executable file
    basing on the os.
    """
    if system_is("Windows"):
        return WINDOWS_ENDING
    elif system_is("Linux"):
        return LINUX_ENDING


def nice_format_for_execute(result):
    """
    The second argument is always going to be None,
    I only care about the first one
    """
    return result[0]


def execute(filename="a"):
    """
    Executes the "a" executable taking care that
    the ending is correct.
    Format the result before outputting it.
    """
    filename += decide_ending()
    result = exec_bash("./" + filename)
    result = nice_format_for_execute(result)
    return result


def delete(string, sub_string):
    """
    Returns the string without the sub_string chars.
    >>> delete("Hello, how are you?","Hello, ")
    how are you?
    """
    string = string.replace(sub_string, "")
    return string


def get_flags():
    """
    Gets eventual compiler flags.
    Flags must be in the first line of the file,
    in the following format:
    // FLAGS -myflag1 -myflag2
    """
    flags = ""
    text = main_text.get(1.0, tk.END)
    flags = ""
    lines = text.splitlines()
    first_line = lines[0]
    if "// FLAGS" in first_line:
        flags += delete(first_line, "// FLAGS")
    return flags


def run():
    """
    Runs the file.
    If there is a compile time error it is shown. #TODO format compile errrors
    Otherwise, if the compilation is successful the result
    is shown in a pop up.
    """
    save(alert=False)
    filename = file_title.get()
    flags = get_flags()
    result = compile_(filename, flags)
    if result == NO_ERROR:
        pop_up.showinfo("The output is: ", execute())
    else:
        pop_up.showinfo("Error found when compiling", result)


# Here the GUI code starts.
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title(TITLE)


menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Open", command=open_)
menubar.add_command(label="Save", command=save)
menubar.add_command(label="Run", command=run)
root.config(menu=menubar)


top = tk.Frame(root)
tk.Label(root, text="Title:").pack(in_=top, side=tk.LEFT)
file_title = tk.Entry(root)
file_title.pack(in_=top, side=tk.RIGHT)
top.pack()


main_text = tk.Text(root)
main_text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It is mostly PEP8 conform, nice! One thing: Use just one empty line between
  functions.
- The imports `datetime`, `glob` and `os` are not used.
- I needed to change the tkinter-imports for python3 on linux:

  ```
  if sys.version_info.major == 2:
      import Tkinter as tk
      import tkMessageBox as pop_up
      import tkFileDialog
  else:
      import tkinter as tk
      import tkinter.messagebox as pop_up
      import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog
  ```
- `exec_bash()`: Please read
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations.
  You pass in data gathered from the document the user edits and could be provided by someone. A possible attack vector would be something like this example:

  ```
  // FLAGS; echo $USER;

  int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {
  }
  ```
- `system_is()/decide_ending()`: This could be simplified using a constant
  dict with a mapping from os-name to file-ending.
- `execute()`: Why the use of `nice_format_for_execute()`? This could be
  simplified to:

  ```
  result = exec_bash("./" + filename + decide_ending())
  return result[0]
  ```
- `delete()`: You could just do `return string.replace(...)`. It would be nice
  to use `str.lstrip()` to just remove the chars from the beginning.
- `get_flags()`: Duplicate variable `flags`. And this could be shorter with
  the side effect of making `delete()` redundant:

  ```
  lines = main_text.get(1.0, tk.END).splitlines()
  first_line = lines[0]
  if first_line.startswith("// FLAGS"):
      return first_line.lstrip("// FLAGS")
  return ""
  ```
- `open_()`: The with statement can fail and would throw an exception:

  ```
  >>> with open("doesnotexist") as fob:
  ...   pass
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doesnotexist'
  ```
- Please wrap the code at the end of the file in a `main()` function. This
  creates the problem of variables like `file_title`. Please do not use
  `global`, but consider wrapping your functions in a class.

Comment: PEP8 requires two lines between functions, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id15.

Comment: @lummax You say that `exec_bash()` is potentially dangerous, still this is a toll for developers and they should know what they are doing. If they really want to damage their computers, they can just run the dangerous shell script directly.